# How to run a parameter while executing a C file?

Tags: c, terminal, arguments

I have a working program that computes the cube of a number in a `compute_cube.c` file. It compiles into `compute_cube`.

Now I would like to run it through the terminal like this:

```
./compute_cube 3
```

And then the terminal would show my program's result (`27`).

How would I go about doing this? What should I be reading up on?

Comment: Command line arguments

Comment: Find `argc` and `argv` in your reference text. That should lead you in the right direction.

Answer (score 2):

Use C language's [`argc` and `argv`](http://crasseux.com/books/ctutorial/argc-and-argv.html):

```
int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc > 1)
        printf("%s", argv[1]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I know its already been answered but... `argc` of course = 0-based number of command line `args` including program name at index 0 and `argv` contains actual command line text.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  if (argc > 1) {
    int n = atoi(argv[1]);
    printf ("%d^3 = %d\n", n, n*n*n);
    return 0;
  }
  else printf("Usage: %s <num>\n", argv[0]);
  return 1;
}
```

Comment: Good answer. I would suggest using `strtol` instead of `atoi`. With `atoi` you have no way of knowing if the argument passed by the user was garbage. With `strtol` you have more control and you can actually detect errors.